# VBA - Export Pivot Table WITHOUT Reference to database

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need to export some tabs to unique excel files, so I can send them to each partner.

The problem is that, when I run my code, each file remains "connected" to the database, so each partner could see how the others are performing and we don't want it.

Could you please help me out? The code is down below:

```
    Sub WorksheetExport()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsDash As Worksheet
    ' Dim wbToSave As Workbook
    Dim filePathToSave As String
    Dim DateString As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim path As String
    
    'DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
    DateString = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       
    'Set wsDash = Worksheets("Admitad")
    wbToSave = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(wbToSave) Then
    
    ' doesn't exist, so create the folder& DateString
              fso.CreateFolder wbToSave

    End If
    
    filePathToSave = wbToSave & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & " " & DateString
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(filePathToSave) Then
    
    ' doesn't exist, so create the folder& DateString
              fso.CreateFolder filePathToSave

    End If
    
    
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

   'If ws.Name = wsDash.Name And (wsDash.Name <> "EXPORT!" And wsDash.Name <> "Clickwise") Then
    'If wsDash.Name <> "EXPORT!" And wsDash.Name <> "helper" And wsDash.Name <> "base" Then
    
        ws.Copy
        
        Set wbToSave = ActiveWorkbook
        teste = wbToSave.Worksheets(1).Name
        wbToSave.SaveAs _
            Filename:=filePathToSave & "\" & wbToSave.Worksheets(1).Name & " " & DateString & ".xlsx", _
            FileFormat:=51
        wbToSave.Close True
        
    'End If
    
Next ws
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Os arquivos se encontram em " & filePathToSave
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to just copy and paste the contents of the tab as string in a new workbook then save it?

Answer (score 0):

I have a file set up where I needed something similar. I just set up my macro to a button. The coding is a bit different based on what I needed but all I have it do is filter my pivot table however I want, click a button, and pastes values only on a new sheet (which severs the connection).

This is a simple version of it for your reference, but it solved my issue with minimal coding and frustration. I manually save my copies, but you can add layers to this as needed if it helps you.

```
Sub Export()
    Dim newbook as Workbook
    Set newbook = Workbooks.Add
    
    Dim rng as Excel.Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySourceSheet").Range("A1:Q1000") 'range I want copied
    
    rng.Copy
    
    With newbook
         With Range("A1") 'where I want it to be pasted to
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
         .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
         End With
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey @Purrple, thanks for the tip. I'll sure try it.